# Scala dependency injection simple pattern

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

I hope you are having a great day!

By the **requirement** of the framework, I have to use inject `Configuration` class and in order to get configuration keys.

The problem is now I have to refactor my code but I can't figure out how can I do that.

---

**Problem**

For the sake of simplicity let's consider a `Sender` class and it's companion object.

```
class Sender(image: File, name: String) {

  def send() = { Sender.s3Client.send(image, name)  }

}

object Sender {

  val accessKey = config.get[String]("accessKey")
  val secretKey = config.get[String]("secretKey")

  val s3Client: AmazonS3 = ... withCredentials ( accessKey, secretKey) ...
}
```

Here I `config.get` method should be an injected object.

**Question**

How can I inject `Configuration` class in this scenario?

I can't use like below because Some other method instantiates this class with image and name param

```
class Sender @Inject() (image: File, name: String, config: Configuration) { ... }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, you can have your own DI container even without using DI Framework.

```
trait ConfigurationModule {

   def config: Configuration

}

trait S3Module {

   def accessKey: String
   def secretKey: String

   lazy val s3Client: AmazonS3 = ... withCredentials ( accessKey, secretKey) ...

}

object YourOwnApplicationContext extends ConfigurationModule with S3Module with ... {

  ...

  lazy config: Configuration = ConfigFactory.load()

  lazy val accessKey = config.get[String]("accessKey")
  lazy val secretKey = config.get[String]("secretKey")

}
```

Now all your dependencies are in `YourOwnApplicationContext`.

So you can do this:

```
class Sender(image: File, name: String) {

  def send() = YourOwnApplicationContext.s3Client.send(image, name)

}
```

You may read these articles:

1. [MacWire](https://github.com/adamw/macwire)
2. [Dependency Injection in Scala using MacWire](http://di-in-scala.github.io/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regarding `ConfigFactory.load()`, actually I don't have access to a method like that. The requirement of the Play framework that I'm using is that I should inject the Configuration(based on JSR 330). As far as I know there is no more Global object(in past versions it was possible to get those values from Global object). 

I appreciate your suggested readings and now I'm going to read those.

Meanwhile could you propose some other approach using guice like DI? Gamsa-hamnida, Thank you!